# Oracle sql: as_of_date function with AM and PM dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-formatting

I have a kind of wired problem here...

I have a column of daily dates from 2011.01 to 2014.04, and I am trying to convert it to month end dates by the `last_day` function. Here is my code:

```
select distinct
    last_day(dates)
from db
```

And my date format looks like this: `02-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM`

I am expecting  a column of all the month end dates from `31-JAN-2011` to `30-APR-2014`. Everything works fine except I have two `31-JAN-14` records.

When I track down this problem, I found it comes from there being a `06-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM` and a `06-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 PM` in my original data. I have verified this is the source of the problem, and all other of my data is in `AM` format.

Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "last_day" function shifts the DAYS part of the Oracle date to the last day of the month but it doesn't touch the hours part.

Look at this:

```
select to_char(last_day(sysdate), 'HH24:MI') from dual;

17:03
```

Instead, try truncating the date before performing last_day:

```
select distinct
   last_day(trunc(dates))
from db
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why:

Someone inserted a record with time portion

Fix:

.. will depend on what you need...

You may delete one record (`based on trunc(dates) <> dates`)

You may remove "time portion" with `UPDATE ... where trunc(dates) <> dates`

You may hide time with `select trunc(dates) ... or select to_char(dates, 'YYYYMMDD')`

You maybe interested to add a CHECK constraint on that field that it always has 0 time.